# JavaScript, Regex, var in pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

right now, i have this replace:

```
var newcontent = newcontent
                .replace(/<div id="container_gallery_"(.*)><\/div>/gi,"");
```

Is it possible to pass a variable in place of `<div id="container_gallery_` ?

My

```
function delAlbum(a) { }
```

performs this replace, and I would like to put the variable `a` into the

-edit-

Thanks for the information provided!
Less hairloss!

Comment: It's simple. Just don't use reglar expressions with HMTL and things like this become easy.

Comment: Since you are using JS, why don't you access the div by DOM function? (There should be a way with jQuery, I don't know about JS, but there surely has to be some way).

Answer (score 2):

You can build up the RegExp via the [object notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and not the shorthand one:

```
function delAlbum(a) {
    var regex = new RegExp( a + '"(.*)><\/div>', 'gi' );

    var newcontent = newcontent
                    .replace( regex,"");
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To put a variable into the regular expression, you need to construct the regular expression as a string and then pass it to the RegExp object constructor like this:

```
var target = a + "(.*)></div>";
var newcontent = newcontent.replace(new RegExp(target, "gi"), "");
```

In general, it is a bad idea to do regex matching on uncontrolled HTML and a really bad idea to do it on HTML that comes from the `.innerHTML` property because there are lots of legal HTML ways to break your regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

As the other responders said, you can use a RegExp constructor for that.  But while you're at it, you should get rid of that `(.*)`.  Assuming it's meant to consume whatever other attributes the `<div>` has, you'll be better off using `[^<>]*`.  That will confine the match to one element at a time; `(.*)` is the ultimate escape artist.

But I'm curious: are you really passing in strings like `<div id="container_gallery_"`, including the first part of the HTML element?  Or are you only passing a replacement for the attribute's value, (e.g. `container_gallery_`)?  If that's the case, this regex should serve you better:

```
var regex = new RegExp('<div\s+"` + (your var) + '"[^<>]*></div>', 'gi' );

I'm assuming the `id` attribute is always in the first position which generally not a safe assumption, but it makes the regex a lot easier, both to write and to read. ;)
```

And don't forget to check the passed-in string for characters that are illegal in an HTML attribute.